# Web Scraping excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** product titles, prices, seller and image url from an eCommerce website. The results need to be copied to active sheet in column A-D. Below code was originally developed for Amazon by one of @QHarr. Any help to update it to get the desired result?

I have included the image how the result will look like. Thanks

```
Public Sub WriteOutProductInfo()

'VBE>Tools>References> Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    ' change the url for the page of amazon from where to copy data
    .Open "GET", "https://www.daraz.lk/catalog/?from=input&q=sarees&ppath=31186:3287", False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

' 1. declare additional headers as variable
  
Dim headers(), titles As Object, prices As Object, original_prices As Object
Dim seller As Object

headers = Array("Title", "Price")

With html
    Set titles = .querySelectorAll(".c3gUW0,.c13VH6")
    Set prices = .querySelectorAll(".------------")
End With

Dim results(), r As Long, priceInfo As String

ReDim results(1 To titles.Length, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

For r = 0 To titles.Length - 1
    results(r + 1, 1) = titles.Item(r).innerText        
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
End With

End sub
```

[image]

Comment: edited please unmark as on hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro you posted is a little creepy for different reasons. Use this to reach your goal:

```
Sub WriteOutProductInfo()

'This macro works on the sheet it's startetd from

Dim browser As Object
Dim url As String
Dim nodesAllOffers As Object
Dim nodeOneOffer As Object
Dim currentRow As Long

  'Row, for title and price for current offer
  currentRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  'Make sure that line 2 is the start line if nothing has been entered in the table yet
  If currentRow = 1 Then currentRow = 2

  'Your sample url
  'You can loop over various urls from a table with the following code
  '(Loop not included here)
  url = "https://www.daraz.lk/catalog/?from=input&q=sarees&ppath=31186:3287"

  'Initialize Internet Explorer, set visibility,
  'call URL and wait until page is fully loaded
  Set browser = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  browser.Visible = False
  browser.navigate url
  Do Until browser.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  'Get all html elements with the css class "c3KeDq" in a node collection
  'These are all offers of the called page, which contain in each case
  'the connected information (title and price)
  '
  'This is a sample of the html code for one offer
  '<div class="c3KeDq">
  '  <div class="c3vCyH">
  '  </div>
  '  <div class="c16H9d">
  '    <a age="0" href="//www.daraz.lk/products/ladies-office-and-saree-wear-brown-i102604104-s1009196133.html?search=1"
  '       title="Ladies Office And Saree Wear - Brown">
  '      Ladies Office And Saree Wear - Brown
  '    </a>
  '  </div>
  '  <div class="c3gUW0">
  '    <span class="c13VH6">
  '      Rs. 1,150
  '    </span>
  '  </div>
  '  <div class="c3lr34">
  '  </div>
  '  <div class="c15YQ9">
  '    <span class="c2i43- c1enUu" title="Sri Lanka">
  '      Sri Lanka
  '    </span>
  '  </div>
  '  <div class="c2attd">
  '    <div class="c31VUX">
  '      <button age="0" type="button" class="ant-btn c1xzE_ ant-btn-primary ant-btn-lg">
  '        ADD TO CART
  '      </button>
  '    </div>
  '  </div>
  '</div>
  Set nodesAllOffers = browser.document.getElementsByClassName("c3KeDq")
  If Not nodesAllOffers Is Nothing Then
    'If we got the node collection
    'We step through all offers and pull the titel and price out
    For Each nodeOneOffer In nodesAllOffers
      'Get title
      ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = getValueByClassName(nodeOneOffer, "c16H9d")
      'Get price
      ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value = getValueByClassName(nodeOneOffer, "c13VH6")
      'Next offer (row)
      currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Next nodeOneOffer
  End If

  'Clean up
  browser.Quit
  Set browser = Nothing
  Set nodesAllOffers = Nothing
  Set nodeOneOffer = Nothing
End Sub
```

And this function:

```
Private Function getValueByClassName(htmlNode As Object, cssClassName As String) As String

'This function works with a single node
'If htmlNode is a node collection, you will got only the first value

Dim nodeByClassName As Object
Dim resultString As String

  'Try to get wanted node
  Set nodeByClassName = htmlNode.getElementsByClassName(cssClassName)(0)
  If Not nodeByClassName Is Nothing Then
    'If we got the class node
    'Take innertext
    resultString = Trim(nodeByClassName.innertext)
  End If

  'Clean up
  Set nodeByClassName = Nothing

  'Return result string
  getValueByClassName = resultString
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you !  Couple of things if you can help more: 1. I want the url of the image in column C, I tried it by it's attribute "c1ZEkM" but didn't work. 2. how can I loop through all the pages if it is more than one e.g. in this case there are 3 pages https://www.daraz.lk/ac/?from=input&q=sarees

Comment: @Damian, Geert Bellekens, Ryan Wildry, SIM, QHarr. I have made the changes to the question but still I am banned from posting. Can you please have a look. Thanks